# django mass email, validation and capturing message id

Tags: django

am building a model in my app to queue email notification using a task from celery it will fire every few minutes. check the queue and send out messages straight from there,

am using the send_mass_mail function from django. Am building a tuple and then then using it with send_mass_mail to fire out all emails. Its very efficient, but there is no trace. It's not returning anything accept a number.

How do I get it to return more details about the fired batch? message id's? statuses of each message? just so I know what was sent and what wasn't.

regards,

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question?